# File transfer support with Twilio IP Messaging / Chat?

Tags: file, ip, twilio, messaging, transfer

I hope not 'too dumb' of a question.  We want to build chat support into our app using Twilio's IP Messaging feature/servce... no problem thus far.

However, does anyone know or can recommend what to use in combination with IP Messaging to also provide for a file transfer feature. Can we use some other Twilio API call for that or do we need to look outside of Twilio for other tools.

If other tools, please do not hesitate to provide some recommendations, if you would. We need to satisfy enterprise-level robustness requirements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Twilio IP Messaging , although currently doesn't support native multimedia/file , its in the [roadmap](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging#coming-soon) .

Whilst its not available , the best way to approach this would be to upload the files to , lets say , a S3 bucket on AWS ( since Twilio is hosted on AWS , this would be your best route ) and then use "attributes"[An optional string metadata field you can use to store any data you wish. The string value must contain structurally valid JSON if specified.] parameter with [/messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/messages#send-a-message-to-a-channel) to store information of these multimedia files

Comment: Hey @am1704, thanks for jumping in to assist the Twilio community on Stackoverflow! Can we send you a shirt to say thanks? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.